# jQuery cycle not working in chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#slider-box').cycle({
                    fx:     'fade',
                    speed:  '700',
                    timeout: 4000,
                    pager:  '#slide-pager'
                });
            });
```

and html is:

// some content

// some content

This is working well in firefox. But not working in IE and chrome.
I have also tried $ sign. But it says function not defined as i am using jQuery at places.

IE says:
Line: 135
Character: 70
Code: 0
Error Message: 'this[...].style' is null or not an object
URL: http://www.waqasalieee.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2

chrome says (console in developer tools):
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the proper solution:
first of all we need to disable default jquery inclusion in wordpress, you can do this by:
open: wp-includes/script-loader.php
comment this line: $scripts->add( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', false, '1.4.2');
Now open your themes header.php
and include this line in header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Problem solved!
Cheers!
Once again thanks to Kim for clicking my mind to think in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your javascript.. maybe you should update your jquery to newest version.

Comment: maybe this should be a comment

Comment: Thanks buddy, i have linked to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js. Its solved my problem.